# Java web service client acesso by VPN

Tags: java, web-services, vpn

im trying to acces a web service by VPn andi mgetting connection refused..
I can ping the adress and i can access web service if im not working with VPN,but this way i cant.
Do i need to do something when im inside VPN??
Code is below..

ps:SoapUI has the same error,too

> Blockquote

```
    HelloWorldService stub = new HelloWorldServiceLocator();
    HelloWorld req = stub.getHelloWorld();
    req.hello();
```

Comment: The better the question, the more likely you will get answered. Please rewrite your question. Your code lacks any context at all - what libraries or classes do you use to connect? What VPN software is at the other end? Where exactly does it fail?.

Comment: i generated my code with eclipse http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/

Comment: Pings do not tell you a lot. First, can you telnet the service (host + port). Second, depending on the VPN setup certain protocols may be blocked...

Comment: Im receiving this message in SOAPUI "error getting response in org-apache.http.conn.HttpPostConnectException: connection to IP refused

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to java web services. This is a networking issue. If you can't ping the machine when you are using VPN you should look into your network topology and routing.

Answer (score 0):

Some VPNs (for example CheckPoint Endpoint Security) override user routing table and route to different host (especially if it is within private range) or  may be unavailble when you try to access them from VPN.